# jQuery - set data() variable from $(this).val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an e-mail form on my website, with four fields. Three text inputs and a text area. Each field has a default value attribute which serves as its label. I would like these values to be automatically unset/reset on their element's focus and focusout events.

I have the following JavaScript/jQuery code, which creates this behaviour.

```
$('input,textarea').data('default', "bleh");
$('input,textarea').focus(function() {
    if($(this).val() === $(this).data('default')) {
            $(this).val('');
    }
});
$('input,textarea').focusout(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '')
    {
            $(this).val($(this).data('default'));
    }
});
```

My problem comes in the storing of the initial `data('default')` attribute. I had tried using `.data('default', $(this).val())`... but apparently that is illegal and `$(this)` is not recognized.

I have tried to find a clean jQuery way to iterate over each of the elements, but I can't seem to find one.

Is there an easy way, using jQuery, to achieve what I want?

Comment: Are you saying the individual default values should be set based on whatever values the fields have when the page first loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, there's no reason to be setting data properties on the element, you can make use of the elements `defaultValue` property:

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function() {
  if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
    this.value = '';
  }
});

$('input, textarea').focusout(function() {
  if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {
    this.value = this.defaultValue;
  }
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHZLC/)

Comment: This works perfectly, and is a much nicer solution that what I was trying. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `this`, because you're not in a callback. You'll have to iterate over each matched element, setting their default one at a time.

The "clean jQuery way" is simply with `each`:

```
$('input,textarea').each(function () {
  $(this).data('default', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @cfs Not within an `each` callback. `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object, hence wrapping it with `$(this)`. And no, `this` (at the point he's attempting to set a default) is *not* a jQuery object. It's probably `window`. He's **not in a callback**, as I said.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try remember each() for next time I need it, but for now I think billyonecan's solution is a lot nicer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You need iterate through the input elements and then set the value to data using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('input,textarea').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('default', $this.val())
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it looks like I was only trying to emulate what .defaultValue can do for me anyway.